# postgresql-server connection password fail for ip option in psql

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, passwords, ip

I try to set up a PostgreSQL-server (to learn Spring).

As I am new to PostgreSQL, I have difficulties to frame my problem.

Problem description:

1. I started postgresql: 
   `● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mo 2017-08-21 19:10:46 CEST; 20min ago
   Process: 28211 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 28211 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

PostgreSQL is running on my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04). So no remote server ect.

2. Trying to populate Postgres with data:
   `sudo psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -f create_soba_psql.sql 
   Password for user postgres: 
   psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Tried pw: postgre, postgres, with pw from current user of OS

BUT 
`sudo -u postgres psql` 
creates a connection
(with pw from current user of OS).

So something new to me to be learned...

What I already tried:

- Resetting pw for postgres with: $ sudo passwd postgres
- Looking into the PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File

[screenshot configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2vlz.png)

I think "peer" should be ok, as I do not connect to a remote server, isn't it?

- Reinstalling PostgreSQL and trying everything again. At least the error did not change...

Do you, dear reader, have a hint what I can try or even have a solution/ explanation what I am doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

in psql session, run:

```
alter user postgres password 'some_pw';
```

quit the session and try:

```
sudo psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -f create_soba_psql.sql
```

when asked use password `some_pw`

Comment: Fantastic!
You solved the problem(= Thank you so much! Based on your answer I did some research to understand what is happening.
Is it correct that the default pw would have been 'password' ?